# FORECAST for only nearest neighbour values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am desperately trying to find how to force FORECAST to only use the nearest neighbour values. Say I have this set:

```
0  |  10
1  |  10
2  |  10
3  |  10
4  |  20
5  |  20
```

Then if I apply FORECAST to a value of 3, it will give me 14.476.

```
 FORECAST(3, y_known, x_known) = 14.47 (I want 10 !)
```

I would like to have a nearest interpolation, so `10` in this case.

How can I indicate to FORECAST that it should use only the two nearest neighbour values?

Comment: Wouldn't 3 give 13.33 using 10,10 and 20, or 15 using just 10 and 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the current value plus one either side, do almost exactly what @pnuts has suggested in the comment e.g. for the point in A3:-

```
=FORECAST(A3,B2:B4,A2:A4)
```

If you only want to use the two nearest neighbours and not the middle one, one way to do it would be from first principles so if the data starts in A2, the point in A3 is predicted by:-

```
=(A3-A2)/(A4-A2)*(B4-B2)+B2
```

If the x-values are equally spaced as in the example, you could also just use AVERAGE:-

```
=AVERAGE(A2,A4)
```